# Problems with an if statement in For loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to insert an If statement in a For loop but keep getting errors.
Code is :

```
For i = 3 To lastRow
    If Range("Q" & i).Value = "Data confirmed" Then Range("Q" & i).Value = ""
    Else
    sh.Cells(i, "Q").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sh.Cells(i, "Q"), Address:="", _
    SubAddress:="", TextToDisplay:="Click To Save"
    End If
    
Next i
```

When the cell contains the value "Data Confirmed" , no hyperlink should be included and the value should be ""
When there is no "Data confirmed" in the cell, a hyperlink should pop up ( see code after the "ELSE")

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: probably problems: 1. the code after `then` should be on a line after `then` instead of on the same line. 2. Cells() should take two numbers as parameters, not any letters.

Comment: oh, never mind, i guess you can use a letter as a parameter for cells() for the column

Comment: This is a code snippet. We cannot know if this is happening in one worksheet or more of them, since you have used the `sh` variable in the `Else` clause. Please do clarify preferably by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64425380/edit)ing your question (post). Best include the complete code from `Sub` to `End Sub`.The part after `Then` definitely has to go into the next line, a line before `Else`.

Comment: That did the trick, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify as much as you can and run the code. Going around different columns will illustrate it better. This one:

```
Sub TestMe()
    
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 3 To 10
        With Sheet1
            If .Range("A" & i) = "Data confirmed" Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = ""
            Else
                .Cells(i, "C").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(i, "D"), Address:="", _
                    SubAddress:="", TextToDisplay:="Click To Save"
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

produces this:

[image]